# Определение после указательного местоимения

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены запятые?

...и за решением этой, им созданной, проблемы завод обратился в авторитетный станкостроительный институт...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, верно. Однако есть варианты.

Уточняться могут согласованные определения со значением цвета, размера, возраста и др.:

Ещё одно, (какое именно?) последнее, сказанье – и летопись окончена моя (Пушкин); Кой-где выглянули женские, (какие именно?) большей частью старушечьи, головы (Тургенев).

Уточняющие определения **могут** конкретизировать общее значение местоимений этот, такой, каждый, один (не в значении числительного, а в значении местоимения) и др.:

Чичиков немного озадачился таким, (каким именно?) отчасти резким, определением (Гоголь); Ни одного, ни санного, ни человеческого, ни звериного, следа не было видно (Л. Толстой); Хотелось отличиться перед этим, (каким именно?) дорогим для меня, человеком (М. Горький).

**Обратите внимание!**

1) Обособление уточняющих согласованных определений – явление достаточно **редкое и во многом зависит от воли пишущего.** Обычно определения с уточняющим значением рассматриваются как однородные, то есть запятая ставится не с двух сторон, а с одной – между определениями.

Быстрыми шагами прошёл я длинную «площадь» кустов, взобрался на холм и... увидел совершенно другие, незнакомые мне места (Тургенев).

Так что можно и не ставить вторую запятую.

Answer (score 0):

...и за решением **этой, им созданной**, проблемы завод обратился в авторитетный станкостроительный институт...

Всё верно, и выделение оборота с двух сторон запятыми  после **указательного местоимения** очень желательно.

1) Из Розенталя: 
 Определительные, **указательные** и притяжательные местоимения **не отделяются** запятой от следующего за ними причастного оборота, тесно примыкая к нему, например: **В этом** забытом людьми уголке я отдыхал все лето.

Но если причастный оборот имеет характер уточнения либо пояснения, то определение обособляется, например: Хотелось отличиться перед **этим**, **дорогим для меня**, человеком. [XXIV. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯХ С ОБОСОБЛЕННЫМИ ЧЛЕНАМИ](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm#_top)

Уточняющие определения могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений этот, тот, такой и др. , например: Затем удивила Дашу «доморощенность» всего **этого**, **так нашумевшего**, дерзновения [XXV. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯХ С УТОЧНЯЮЩИМИ ПОЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ И ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ ЧЛЕНАМИ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/46.htm)

2) Почему следует обратить внимание именно **на указательные местоимения?** Указательные местоимения обычно не требуют раскрытия содержания предмета (какой именно?), из контекста этот предмет и так известен, а в определительном обороте просто сообщаются о нем **дополнительные сведения** (поэтому оборот желательно **обособить,   а не отделять запятой**).