# Нужна ли запятая? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

Уточнение ли это? Нужна ли запятая и почему?

**Это обусловлено следующими (,) присущими только указанному материалу особенностями...**

Comment: Это, видимо, тот же случай, что рассматривался здесь: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428854/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: Думаю, да, этот же случай.Запятая нужна из-за оттенка пояснения ( в причастном обороте есть частица только). Без частицы можно было бы запятую вообще не ставить: Это обусловлено следующими  присущими указанному материалу особенностями. А здесь нужна запятая - оборот как бы поясняет прилагательное "следующими", но акцента на пояснении нет, запятая как при однородных определениях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом случае запятая ставится по формальному признаку: **Если причастный оборот (= определительный оборот) стоит после определения-прилагательного и перед определяемым словом** (т. е. разрывает непосредственную связь прилагательного и существительного), то между определениями ставится запятая: Даже старые, серыми лишаями покрытые ветви деревьев зашептали о прошлых днях (М. Г.);

§ 38. [Знаки препинания при однородных определениях](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)

Здесь нет уточнения или пояснения, отношения между определениями скорее неоднородные, но запятая ставится, как при однородных членах.